# what is the best Method to save a palette of colors availbe for a prduct?

Tags: php, mysql

in Mysql 
what is the best Method to save a list of colors available for a product?
there are alot of products
and every product may have more than two color (ex:fabric color1,fabric color2,wood color).

Comment: make a colour table with foreign key of product

Comment: What is the best way to store a list in a database?

Answer (score 2):

I would go with Product table, Colors table and then table to connect them (id_product, id_color). This was any product can have more than one color, and you can easily find all product with selected color. You can make similar for other attribute.

But you might want to have separate table for product attributes (similarly to color)

Answer (score -1):

There many ways you can do that. here are my ways 
1:make a colour table with foreign key of product 
2:if you want a single table then save colours with comma separated or some special character(like | )
 with each product

Comment: Option 1 introduces redundancy in the colour table. Option 2 defeats the very purpose of a RDBMS. See: [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3653462/1446005).

Answer (score -2):

You can use html5 colorpicker for inputs or manually input the colors code/name etc and have multiple input fields per product get them as an array while saving in database you should have a color column in your products table and then use php's implode function to make the array as string separated by commas and save the string in the color column. While fetching the data you should use php's explode function to get the respective colors in the respective fields of a specific product.

Comment: This is exactly what you should not do

Comment: @Strawberry can you please explain what is wrong with such approach? If you know the better way why don't you give your answer.

Comment: Volvox's answer is satisfactory

Comment: This approach defeats the very purpose of a RDBMS. See: [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3653462/1446005).